# Returning incomplete HTML content when using Selenium to scrape information on the website

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape product information on one websites

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url = 'https://www.gap.com/browse/category.do?cid=5664&nav=meganav%3AWomen%3ACategories%3AJeans#pageId=0&department=136'
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')  
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path='/Users/wangxining/Downloads/chromedriver_mac_arm64/chromedriver')
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(4)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'product-card category-page-zu5l9z'})
```

It should show more rows when find product cards

Answer (score 0):

It's not showing more rows when finding product cards because at first, the website loads only a few products (here, it's 8).

If you want to load more, you need to scroll down the window to load more content(product cards) before you get the page source to parse with bs4.

Here is the implementation,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url = 'https://www.gap.com/browse/category.do?cid=5664&nav=meganav%3AWomen%3ACategories%3AJeans#pageId=0&department=136'
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)
sleep(2)

# here, I'm scrolling 10 times
for _ in range(10):
    # scroll down by height 3000
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 3000);")
    sleep(2)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
products = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'product-card category-page-zu5l9z'})

print(len(products))
```

output:

```
190
```

you see, 190 (it can vary) product cards are loaded after scrolling 10 times by a window height of 3000. you can load more product cards by scrolling more times.

Hope it answers your question.